# Cumulated Cohorts in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table :

| cohort | month cohort | orders | cumulated orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 0 | 126 | 126 |
| 2021-01 | 1 | 5 | 131 |
| 2021-01 | 2 | 4 | 135 |
| 2021-02 | 0 | 131 | 131 |
| 2021-02 | 1 | 9 | 140 |
| 2021-02 | 2 | 8 | 148 |

And now I want to have the following table where I divide each repeat orders by the number of orders of month 0 :

| cohort | month cohort | orders | cumulated orders | cumulated in % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 0 | 126 | 126 | 100% |
| 2021-01 | 1 | 5 | 131 | 104% |
| 2021-01 | 2 | 4 | 135 | 107% |
| 2021-02 | 0 | 131 | 131 | 100% |
| 2021-02 | 1 | 9 | 140 | 107% |
| 2021-02 | 2 | 8 | 148 | 114% |

My only hint is to create a CASE statement, but I don't want each month to update the query by adding the line

```
WHEN cohort="2021-08" THEN cumulated orders / 143
```

where 143 is the number of orders of cohort 2021-08 at month cohort =0

Has someone got an idea how to get this table ?

Answer (score 1):

A `case` expression isn't needed.  You can use `first_value()`:

```
select t.*,
       ( cumulated_order /
         first_value(orders) over (partition by cohort order by month_cohort)
       ) as ratio
from t;
```

If you really wanted a `case`, you could use:

```
select t.*,
       ( cumulated_order /
         max(case when month_cohort = 0 then orders end) over (partition by cohort)
       ) as ratio
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select *, 
  round(100 * cumulated_orders / 
    sum(if(month_cohort = 0, orders, 0)) over(partition by cohort) 
  ) as cumulated_in_percent
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]